# RestTemplate: login by certificate

Tags: java, spring, authentication, httpclient, resttemplate

I am writing a java rest-client to fetch data from the web App. I am trying to use client authentication(login using client certificate) mechanism using spring's `RestTemplate` to get authenticated on server.

Here are the steps that I did.

Server side:

1. Configure the web server to allow certificate based login. Set "clientAuth"= "want" in server.xml
2. Create a clients x509 certificate and add it into servers truststore.

Client Side

3. Initialize `RestTemplate` with clients trustStore and keyStore. For this I used org.apache.commons.httpclient.contrib.ssl.AuthSSLProtocolSocketFactory.
   `AuthSSLProtocolSocketFactory` is initialized with client keystore in `PKCS12` format, and client truststore (jks format).

Code looks like this:

```
CommonsClientHttpRequestFactory factory = (CommonsClientHttpRequestFactory) restTemplate.getRequestFactory();
HttpClient client = factory.getHttpClient();
client.getState().setAuthenticationPreemptive(false);
Protocol myHttps = new Protocol(HTTPS, secureProtocolSocketFactory, DEFAULT_HTTPS_PORT);
Protocol.registerProtocol(HTTPS, myHttps);
client.getHostConfiguration().setHost("localhost", DEFAULT_HTTPS_PORT, myHttps);
```

4. When I am making rest calls into server I am expecting the request to get authenticated by certificate. But I am getting http 403-forbidden error. It seems that restTemplate is trying to authenticate the request by basicCredentials, where my intent is to authenticate using certificate.

Following is the output logged by http client:

```
MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager:390 - HttpConnectionManager.getConnection:  config = HostConfiguration[host=https://<server-ip>], timeout = 0
MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$ConnectionPool:739 - Allocating new connection, hostConfig=HostConfiguration[host=<server-ip>]
HttpMethodDirector:160 - Preemptively sending default basic credentials
HttpMethodDirector:277 - Authenticating with BASIC <any realm>@<server-ip>:443
HttpMethodParams:355 - Credential charset not configured, using HTTP element charset
HttpConnection:691 - Open connection to 10.112.253.152:443
HttpMethodBase:1235 - Adding Host request header
RestTemplate:559 - GET request for "https://<server-ip>:443/url/" resulted in 403 (Forbidden)
```

Is there anything else that needs to be configured on `RestTemplate` to get authenticated using client certificate?